# ASP.NET/Entity : Issue with my Array Index

Tags: c#, arrays

I have managed to pull out the `FirstorDefault()` in the Query, however, some of these address types in the database actually have more than 1 address: therefore, I am trying to build an array of every address regarding each one.

The current code:

```
int counter = 0;
        string queryID = "";
        List<string> busAddr = new List<string>();
        while (counter != busIDs.Count)
        {
            queryID = busIDs[counter];
            var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c).ToArray();
            int gath = 0;
            if ((gathered[gath] as tblbus_address) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((gathered[gath] as tblbus_address).Address1))
                {
                    var address = gathered[gath] as tblbus_address;
                    string test = "";
                    while (gath != address.Address1.Length)
                    {
                        var all = address.Address1;
                        test += address.Address1.ToString() + ",";
                    }
                    busAddr.Add(test);
                }
                else
                {
                    busAddr.Add("No address for this type exists...");
                }
                counter++;
                gath++;
            }
```

I am receiving an error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

at this line:

`if ((gathered[gath] as tblbus_address) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((gathered[gath] as tblbus_address).Address1))`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know this structure is the issue but I cannot think how to approach the situation.

Comment: Got to check for empty array `gathered` if query returned no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the element `gathered[gath]` when there are no items in `gathered`. Adding a check for null and Any will help you

```
if(gathered!=null && gathered.Any() 
  && (gathered[gath] as tblbus_address) != null 
  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((gathered[gath] as tblbus_address).Address1))
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: That stopped my error thank-you & fixed it all! I have another issue, it seems now that instead of counting how many where in that element it just appends them all to `test` in the string here: `while (gath != address.Address1.Length)
                        {
                            var all = address.Address1;
                            test += address.Address1.ToString() + ",";
                        }` any idea to why?

Comment: Couldnt understand what you need to do.  You are appending it to `test += address.Address1.ToString()`. You will be getting all that text. whose count are you looking for? gathered.Length you mean?

Comment: Oh, appologies. I am using that because I want an array of all the addresses that one company has per index. Then later, I will just `.split(",")` because I am using JavaScript front end to allow searches and stuff.

Comment: Ya, marked it :) Thank-you for that @CarbineCoder !